# Relationship between html video elements and page load events?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I was reading the [videojs setup documentation](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html) and came across this line

> On the modern web, a `<video>` element often does not exist when the page finishes loading.

I tried searching for an explanation for this on the [MDN web docs for the  tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), but did not find anything to explain the above statement. The only clue I found is that the doc briefly mentions that "The `<video>` element is a replaced element".

So my questions are:

1. What is the state of a `<video>` element on the `window.load` event?
2. What is does the `<video>` element being a replaced element mean?
3. How does a `<video>` element not exist when a page finishes loading?

Answer (score 0):

The wording is clunky. It just means that the automatic setup won't work if you add the `<video>` or `<video-js>` element after the page has loaded.